# Can't compile test kernel module

Tags: c, makefile, kernel, kernel-module

I have this test file

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int init_module(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void cleanup_module(void){
    printk(KERN_INFO, "I wanna kill my self tbh\n");
}

module_init(init_module);
module_exit(cleanup_module);
```

and this make file

```
obj-m += test.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I'm not too sure what it means but I get an error saying that it couldn't find `Makefile` in the current directory and a file and folder are left in the current directory along with the source file and makefile, those files are `.cache.mk` file and `.tmp_versions` folder.

I just run the `make` command and this is the output I get:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.8-1-ARCH/build M=/home/[user]/projects/c/test modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.15.8-1-ARCH/build'
scripts/Makefile.build:45: /home/[user]/projects/c/test/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/[user]/projects/c/test/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1510: _module_/home/[user]/projects/c/test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/4.15.8-1-ARCH/build'
make: *** [makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You may want to put some context on your build (the exact command you used to try to build and the output).

Comment: edited, added command and output

Comment: Ok, so first question, does `/home/[user]/projects/c/test/Makefile` exist?  (I noticed that it says `make: *** [makefile:4: all] Error 2`, with emphasis on the lowercase `m`....)

Comment: I didn't know it was supposed to be uppercase

Comment: Does switching to uppercase fix the problem?   I just looked at the kbuild documentation and it says that makefiles can be either `'Kbuild'` or `'Makefile'`, with quotes which implies case sensitivity, but it would be easy to miss.

Comment: Yes it did fix it, I just wasn't sure if  I could comment that since SO rules discourage the "this worked thanks" type comments, and since yours wasn't an answer I couldn't mark it as correct or anything.